# minted not working on mac

Tags: minted

I am using texmaker on a Mac and I tired to use the minted package with this code

```
\documentclass[12pt,A4]{article}
\usepackage{minted}
\begin{document}

\begin{minted}{python}

    def __init__(self, x, y): 
        self.x=x
        self.y=y

\end{minted}

\end{document}
```

but when compiling my code I get the following error:

```
! Package minted Error: You must have `pygmentize' installed to use this package
```

However I actually did install the package as described using

```
sudo easy_install Pygments
```

I even tried restarting. Still getting the same error.

I really don't see how to fix this error, can someone help me?

When creating the pdf as suggested by egreg the resulting pdf looks like this:

```
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin
/opt/local/bin
/opt/local/sbin
/opt/local/bin
/opt/local/sbin
/usr/bin
/bin
/usr/sbin
/sbin
/usr/local/bin
/usr/texbin
/usr/X11/bin
Is there pygmentize?
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/pygmentize
```

Judging from that there is Pygmentize on my mac?!

Comment: Do you have `pygmentize` in your `$PATH`?  Open a terminal and try whether `pygmentize` is resolved.  If not, locate it on your hard drive and set the `$PATH` accordingly.  That may resolve your problem.

Comment: if i do 'echo $PATH'
I get '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin:/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/texbin:/usr/X11/bin' I have no idea what that means, sorry I'm not so much into using the terminal...

Comment: If you want to avoid the terminal then it's best to use a TeX only solution such as the `listings` package.

Comment: Works fine here but python is here : `/Library/Python and pygmentize` is here :  `/usr/local/bin/pygmentize`. Perhaps you can create a symbolic link into  /usr/local/bin/. I don't work with `/opt` (macport) because we get always this kind of problem !

Comment: My test works fine, but `pygmentize` is in `/usr/local/bin`

Comment: I moved `pygmentize` to `/usr/local/bin` , now it works. Thank you very much!

Comment: All of a sudden, after using minted for almost a year, the same problem is appearing again. I used it for the last time on Monday and I did not install or change anything in between. Any ideas why this issue reappeared? (I already tried restarting...)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Write a file `path.tex` containing exactly this:

```
\catcode`:=\active
\def:{\par}

\parindent0pt\tt

\input|"echo $PATH"

\bigskip

Is there pygmentize?

\input|"which pygmentize"

\bye
```

and run from the Terminal the command

```
pdftex --shell-escape path
```

You'll see in the produced `path.pdf` file what `pdftex` sees as `PATH`. If there's a path after "Is there pygmentize?" you'll be OK.

Now it's only a question of telling Texmaker that you want to execute external programs such as `pygmentize`: go to the "Preferences" menu in Texmaker and choose the "Commands" tab. In line next to "PdfLaTeX" there should be

```
"/usr/texbin/pdflatex" -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode %.tex
```

Change it into

```
"/usr/texbin/pdflatex" -synctex=1 -shell-escape -interaction=nonstopmode %.tex
```

Beware that this opens some security issues, so remove `-shell-escape` when typesetting documents you get from non trusted sources.

A safer way could be to define a "User command": go to the menu User > User Commands > Edit User Commands and in the upper space write something such as "pdftex-shell-escape"; in the lower space write the string above. You'll have a shortcut for using the shell escape only when you choose to, by pressing <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>

Comment: I added the results I got to my opening post!

Comment: I already had it like that, so this is not the error. (Still I deleted what I had copied your line in there, tried and am still getting the same error)

Comment: @Zwähnia Would you please add a minimal example to your question?

Comment: @egreg I just spent three hours trying to get minted working on an old TeXLive 2010 on an old OpenBSD 5.1. As soon as I added -interaction=nonstopmode to -shell-escape thing went without a glitch in-spite of the fake warning that I do not have pygmentize (which was B.S. of course). Sir you really rock when it comes to TeX. Thank you so much!!!

Answer (score 12):

I just encountered the same issue and copying pygmentize from `/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/bin/pygmentize` to `/usr/local/bin` resolved the problem for me.

Comment: This was it. /usr/local/bin/pygmentize was not being updated. easy_install Pygments showed `Installing pygmentize script to /usr/local/share/python` so I copied that file over /usr/local/bin/pygmentize and it all worked.

Answer (score 1):

The OP reports the following error message:

```
! Package minted Error: You must have `pygmentize' installed to use this package
```

The first thing to do is to make sure that Pygments is installed on your machine (the OP has already done this). Enter the following into a terminal:

```bash
python3 -m pip show Pygments
which pygmentize

# To install Pygments:
# python3 -m pip install Pygments
```

On a recent MacOS, it is likely that you encounter the above error, even if Pygments is installed. This is because GUI applications such as TeXShop or Texmaker are not able to see your environment variables (unless they are launched from a Terminal). As a consequence, the PATH environment variable is not the same for GUI Applications. Unless pygmentize is installed under /usr/local/bin, the GUI will not be able to localize the command-line utility.

**Workaround 1**: Add a symbolic link to /usr/local/bin.

```bash
ln -s /path/to/pygmentize /usr/local/bin/pygmentize
```

**Workaround 2**: Run your your TeX editor from a Terminal. For TeXShop:

```bash
/Applications/TeXShop.app/Contents/MacOS/TeXShop
# Or with path to source file
/Applications/TeXShop.app/Contents/MacOS/TeXShop path/to/tex/file.tex
```

**Workaround 3**: Use `launchctl` to set GUI-visible environment variables. I am not so versed with `launchctl`, which is why I just provide [this link](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/51677/) to a related post.

I am not sure if this workaround still works, as the way launchctl works has changed under newer macOS, [see here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/389023/).

Comment: +1 My previous fix for this was to put the symlink in `/Library/TeX/texbin` but this has the disadvantage of being deleted when I install each year's new MacTeX distribution. It never occurred to me to put the symlink in `/usr/local/bin`. My pygmentize is installed with conda so I just did `ln -s ~/miniconda3/bin/pygmentize /usr/local/bin/pygmentize` and everything works fine.

Answer (score 1):

My solution using TexMaker on macOS Monterey was:

1. install the package using PiP3 (pip3 install pygments)
2. optional: update pip as suggested when installing the package (I have Xcode): /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/python3 -m pip install --upgrade pip
3. add the path of python 3.x to sudo nano /etc/paths (in my case it was /Users/neogene/Library/Python/3.9/bin/), because "which pygmentize" was not detecting the app without setting this new path added (note: close and restart the terminal).
4. Add to TexMaker config the -shell-escape to both the commands(Latex and pdflatex) before last parameter %.tex
5. Add the same path to the field "Add to PATH" in the same settings windows pointing to /Users/neogene/Library/Python/3.9/bin/

Maybe the path addition to the etc/paths is useless but without it in terminal I was unable to find the binary.

[image: The TexMaker setup for MAC]

Answer (score 0):

Use `which pygmentize` to find the path for **pygmentize** first in **Mac OS terminal**, and then copy it to `/usr/local/bin`.