# Minted working from terminal but not Texpad

Tags: minted, python

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [minted not working on mac](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/48018/minted-not-working-on-mac)

I'm using the minted package in latex on my mac (running lion). Now when I use the terminal to type

```
pdflatex -shell-escape MintedProblem.tex
```

it compiles fine and the resultant pdf looks perfect. When I try and typset the exact same document through Texpad (I assume any other IDE also) I just get a load of errors pertaining to the MintedProblem.out.pyg file. I have set up in preferences to use -shell-escape but this hasn't fixed it. Any ideas? My $PATH is shown below in case this sheds some light on things

```
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin:/Users/Philip/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@rails3tutorial2ndEd/bin:/Users/Philip/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/bin:/Users/Philip/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/bin:/Users/Philip/.rvm/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/X11/bin:/usr/local/git/bin:/usr/texbin
```

All the errors are of the following form

```
Undefined control sequence. (...err}{\PYZbs{}}\PY{n}{relax}\PY{p}{\PYZpc{}}...)
```

Below is a minimal working file (working from terminal, not Texpad)

```
\documentclass[12pt, titlepage]{article}
\usepackage{minted}
\begin{document}
\newpage

\begin{minted}[mathescape,
               linenos,
               numbersep=5pt,
               gobble=2,
               frame=lines,
               framesep=2mm]{csharp}
  string title = "This is a Unicode π in the sky"
  /*
  Defined as $\pi=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{P_n}{d}$ where $P$ is the perimeter
  of an $n$-sided regular polygon circumscribing a
  circle of diameter $d$.
  */
  const double pi = 3.1415926535
\end{minted}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks but the solutions offered in that link don't work, pygmentize is in the path (I tried the test suggested)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I had the same problem -- working from Terminal but not in Texpad. I solved it by tweaking my Preferences for Texpad. In the typesetting pane, I enabled -shell-escape (off by default) and disabled the option to hide the intermediate files. I suspect that the error arises when pygments looks for a file but it has been named in such a way that it is not found.

I hope this helps.

Billy

Comment: In minted 2.0alpha3 they added an outputdir option.  
 
Use `\usepackage[outputdir=.texpadtmp]{minted}`, and then you only have to enable -shell-escape, and not hide intermediate files.