# Minted working from terminal but not Texpad

Tags: minted

I'm using the minted package in latex on my mac (running lion). Now when I use the terminal to type

```
pdflatex -shell-escape My_Ruby_Notes.tex
```

it compiles fine and the resultant pdf looks perfect. When I try and typset the exact same document through Texpad (I assume any other IDE also) I just get a load of errors pertaining to the My_Ruby_Notes.out.pyg file. I have set up in preferences to use -shell-escape but this hasn't fixed it. Any ideas? My $PATH is shown below in case this sheds some light on things

> /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin:/Users/Philip/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@rails3tutorial2ndEd/bin:/Users/Philip/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/bin:/Users/Philip/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/bin:/Users/Philip/.rvm/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/X11/bin:/usr/local/git/bin:/usr/texbin

All the errors are of the following form

```
Undefined control sequence. (...err}{\PYZbs{}}\PY{n}{relax}\PY{p}{\PYZpc{}}...)
```

Below is a minimal working file (working from terminal, not Texpad)

```
\documentclass[12pt, titlepage]{article}
\usepackage{minted}
\begin{document}
\newpage

\begin{minted}[mathescape,
               linenos,
               numbersep=5pt,
               gobble=2,
               frame=lines,
               framesep=2mm]{csharp}
  string title = "This is a Unicode π in the sky"
  /*
  Defined as $\pi=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{P_n}{d}$ where $P$ is the perimeter
  of an $n$-sided regular polygon circumscribing a
  circle of diameter $d$.
  */
  const double pi = 3.1415926535
\end{minted}

\end{document}
```

Comment: You need to post those errors.

Comment: Using Emacs+AucTeX your last MWE works for me (on Mac OS X). But the unicode-"π" in the title makes trouble. Deleting it, or compiling with luaLaTeX works though.

Comment: I tried deleting the unicode-"π" but it made no difference unfortunately. It must be an issue with Texpad. I contacted their support (who are great) so hopefully they can help.

Comment: Texpad developers here. Minted currently doesn't work with the hidden directory option in preferences. Works otherwise. We will submit a fix for this in due course.

Comment: @jkcl [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) I've converted your answer to a comment, as that fits the style of the site better.

Answer (score 2):

In OS X, GUI applications don't get changes that are made to `PATH` (or any other environment variables like `TEXINPUTS`) in `.profile` or `.bashrc`.  Thus you have to set them so they are available for GUI applications.  See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/603785/environment-variables-in-mac-os-x/4567308#4567308) for details.

I don't know if that's your problem since you don't specify what the error messages are, but it's quite possible.

Comment: Thanks for the help, I read through the link but can't seem to make sense of it. The errors I am receiving in Texpad are all of the form

Comment: Undefined control sequence. (...err}{\PYZbs{}}\PY{n}{relax}\PY{p}{\PYZpc{}}...)   so it does seem to be that the program is just not managing to 'use' python

Comment: Okay, but maybe python can't run which then doesn't create an intermediate tex file where they are defined.  I don't know how minted works, but a minimal non-working example and/or the full error log would be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Are you using "-output-directory" to compile? There is an open issue that makes minted ignore this parameter and the produced error is the same you report.

Reference: http://code.google.com/p/minted/issues/detail?id=88

Answer (score 1):

My solution to this problem was the following:

1. Enable "Shell Escape"
2. Disable "Hide intermediate files"
3. Make a symbolic link to pygmentize from `/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/bin/pygmentize` to `/usr/local/bin`

Answer (score 0):

For minted 1.7, in addition to enabling -shell-escape, disable the option to hide the intermediate files. (per [Billy](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/64673/44644).)

In minted 2.0alpha3 there is an outputdir option. If you install it (or later), you can use: 
`\usepackage[outputdir=.texpadtmp]{minted}`, and still hide intermediate files.