# Cannot get 'pygmentize' to work correctly on mac

Tags: minted, pygments

I am using TeXworks on Mac osX 10.7.5 and I'm trying to compile some python code within my tex file but with limited success.

My tex file looks like:

```
\documentclass[12pt,A4]{article}
\usepackage{minted}
\begin{document}

\begin{minted}{python}

    def __init__(self, x, y): 
        self.x=x
        self.y=y

\end{minted}

\end{document}
```

When I run the tex file with the command:

```
pdflatex --shell-escape path.tex
```

I get the following error:

```
! Package minted Error: You must have `pygmentize' installed to use this packag
e.
```

The strange thing is, when I run the command, then type "quit". The PDF is produced as expected but how can I get it to produce the file without the error?

I have installed the latest version of minted and pygments. The terminal finds pygmentize:

```
ucbthsa-2:bin ucbthsa$ which pygmentize
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/Current/bin/pygmentize
```

I have had a look at another similar [question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/48018/minted-not-working-on-mac) but it has not helped

Comment: My system says `/usr/local/bin/pygmentize`; how did you install it?

Comment: with easy_install

Comment: What's the response of `echo $PATH`?

Comment: `/Users/ucbthsa/tcoffee/Version_9.03.r1318/bin:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/Current/bin:/sw/bin:/sw/sbin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/X11/bin:/usr/texbin:/usr/X11R6/bin
`

Comment: On none of my machines I have Python as a framework; can you try moving `/Library/...` later in `$PATH`?

Comment: Tried it and it worked. Not sure why though. Thanks for your help

Comment: You might try adding that path to the list in TeXworks: in Preferences, Typesetting tab, you find a list; add `/Library/...` at the top and see if it works

Answer (score 3):

Recently I had the same problem. The issue was that *TeXworks* has different *PATH* environment from your terminal. My solution was to create a symbolic link to *pygmentize* from `/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/bin/pygmentize` to `/usr/local/bin`.