# Pygmentize not working properly with minted package in TexShop on OS X

Tags: mactex, texshop, minted, pygments

I am using TexShop on mac OS X 10.11.1 and I'm trying to output some Python code inside my LaTeX document.

Here is an example of a document I would want to produce :

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[francais]{babel}
\usepackage{minted}
\begin{document}

\begin{minted}{python}

    def __init__(self, x, y): 
        self.x=x
        self.y=y

\end{minted}

\end{document}
```

My LaTeX compile command is `pdflatex --file-line-error --synctex=1 --shell-escape --interaction=nonstopmode`.

When the command is run directly from the terminal, it works fine. But whenever I try to compile the document from TexShop, I get the following error :

```
 sh: /Library/TeX/texbin/pygmentize: cannot execute binary file
```

I also got this error previously :

```
sh: /Library/TeX/texbin/pygmentize: access denied
```

I have Python installed, minted package up to date, pygmentize installed and located at `~/anaconda/bin/pygmentize`, with symbolic links the following directories : `/usr/local/bin/`, `/usr/local/texlive/2015/bin/x86_64-darwin/` and `/Library/Tex/texbin/`.

Now, what can I do to get minted to work

By the way, if I run this test file

```
\catcode`:=\active
\def:{\par}

\parindent0pt\tt

\input|"echo $PATH"

\bigskip

Is there pygmentize?

\input|"which pygmentize"

\bye
```

I get

```
/Users/philippe/anaconda/bin
/usr/local/bin
/usr/bin
/bin
/usr/sbin
/sbin
/Library/TeX/texbin
Is there pygmentize?
/Users/philippe/anaconda/bin/pygmentize
```

Comment: Apparently, TexShop looks for `pygmentize` at the wrong location.

Comment: I don't think so since the error refers to the right location of the `pygmentize` file (`/Library/TeX/texbin/pygmentize`). The error would be different I suppose if the file was not found.

Comment: Ok, found it. I replaced the symbolic link in `/Library/Tex/texbin/` by an actual copy of `pygmentize` and it works fine!

Comment: How do you add /Users/... to your PATH? TeXShop is not starting a login shell so .profile (or .bash_profile) isn't executed. A standard place for placing application like pygmentize is in /usr/local/bin.

Comment: I wonder if here an answer explaining why this is needed might be useful?

Comment: See also [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/48018) related post.

Answer (score 22):

[I had the same problem](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/281151/how-to-invoke-minted-with-python3) and it took me a while until I realized it was TeXShop causing all the trouble. Like you already mentioned, you need a reference to `pygmentize` within `/Library/TeX/texbin`, but it's sufficient to create a symlink instead of a copy:

```
sudo ln -s "$(which pygmentize)" /Library/TeX/texbin/pygmentize
```

Comment: ```sudo ln -s $(which pygmentize) pygmentize```

Comment: @jiun Thanks, will adapt the answer accordingly.

Comment: I'd used `command -v` as `which` isn't really reliable like this (although it's very commonly used)

Comment: The symbolic link has saved my night on macOS/MacTeX too, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I had pygments installed, but I discovered later that is was related with the python 3 version and I believe that TexShop was trying to use the python 2 version. So I installed python 2 using brew and pigments using pip2. It worked!