# How to invoke minted with python3

Tags: mactex, texshop, minted, python, pygments

I have 2 versions of Python on my machine. Version 2.7.10 can be invoked with `python`, whereas `python3` uses 3.5.0 under the hood.

I'd like to use `minted` with `python3`, which is why I installed Pygments via `pip3`. When I compile a LaTeX document that contains `minted` macros, it can't find the library. I assume `minted` uses the standard `python` command and therefore version 2.7.10, which doesn't have Pygments installed.

Is there a way to tell `minted` to switch to version 3?

**EDIT:** [As pointed out by G. Poore](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/281152/92943), `minted` invokes `pygmentize`. Although `which pygmentize` points to Pygments under version 3, I tried to set it manually:

```
\usepackage{minted}
\renewcommand{\MintedPygmentize}{/path/to/pygmentize}
```

Unfortunately I still get `You must have 'pygmentize' installed to use this package` with `minted` 2.1.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I figured out that in my particular case TeXShop was causing the error. One must create a symlink within `/Library/TeX/texbin` to `pygmentize` ([see this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/281188/92943)). Afterwards you can also omit to reset `\MintedPygmentize`.

Answer (score 4):

`minted` invokes the `pygmentize` script, which provides a command-line interface to Pygments. If `minted` can't find `pygmentize`, then the command-line scripts for Python 3 aren't available, and you probably need to modify your PATH.

Comment: Using a Debian-based Docker image with `python3` available and `pygmentize` installed for that interpreter, I ran into this confusing problem. `minted` *mainly* works because `pygmentize` was available, but stuff like `autogobble` and `\inputminted`, which call `python -c`, didnt' work. Ideally, both programs need to be available. The `python` -> `python3` aliasing can be done via symlinking or `update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/python python /usr/bin/python3 1` on Debian. I saw the `sh: python not found` error but had incorrectly assumed it switched to `python3` (but it's `pygmentize`).