# Using the minted package with Temaker produces 'pygmentize' error

Tags: texmaker, minted

Using Texmaker 5.04 on Windows 10 (with Python installed and up-to-date via Anaconda), I'm trying to compile the minimal example provided in the [minted documentation](http://tug.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/minted/minted.pdf).  I expanded the command string for PdfLaTeX in Texmaker to be:

```
 pdflatex -synctex=1 -shell-escape -interaction=nonstopmode %.tex
```

Now, I'm getting the Package minted error, "You must have `pygmentize' installed to use this package."

I have seen similar problems reported, and they indicate an issue with TexMaker not finding pygmentize.  I used the Windows Subsystem for Linux (WSL) to investigate.  'which pygmentize' produces:

```
/home/owner/.local/bin/pygmentize
```

and /home/owner/.local/bin is the very first part of my $PATH variable.  I've tried the solutions presented in other posts, such as [using a symbolic link](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/281151/how-to-invoke-minted-with-python3), but I've been unsuccessful.  It is a bit confusing in the nether worlds between Windows 10, WSL, and Texmaker, trying to figure out where Texmaker is looking and why it's not finding the pygmentize file.  I appreciate your help!

[Update]

Part of my confusion is trying to understand who's running the show... Windows, WSL, TexMaker, or even MikTeX.  My WSL approach was probably off the mark.  I did subsequently use the Windows 10 MikTeX console to see what I could install there.  No immediate help there, but I did stumble upon the [pythonhighlight package](https://github.com/olivierverdier/python-latex-highlighting).  (See also this [post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/83882/how-to-highlight-python-syntax-in-latex-listings-lstinputlistings-command)).  It worked right out of the box.  It may not be as feature-packed as minted purports to be, but it's much lower on the frustration index, and it appears to fit my current need.

Comment: are you using a WSL version of texmaker and texlive ? If not the WSL path would not normally be available to a windows application it would be simpler to install a windows pygmentize i would guess. (or use a linux texlive via wsl)

Comment: Thanks for the response, David!  Added more to the post...

Comment: to get pygmentize to run in miktex you need a windows python so that `pygmentize` would run in a `cmd` window. You can not run wsl applications (safely) from windows, and the PATH you see in a wsl bash is the virtual path as seen from wsl not the path that a windows application would need to find the program