# error: `pygmentize.sty' not found

Tags: texstudio, minted, pygments

I am trying to use `minted` package, which has a dependency of the program called `pygmentize`. I installed this but did not working well. Then i did [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/62003/135597) But still showing the error:

```
File `pymentize.sty' not found.
```

when i write this:

```
\usepackage{pymentize}
\usepackage{minted}
```

I am using mac sierra and texstudio. Help me please.

Comment: `pygmentize` is not a LaTeX package. It is a Python package. So you should remove the `pygmentize` package import (you may have to install `pygments` which includes `pygmentize` using the Python package manager to let `minted` work afterwards).

Comment: yes, i installed pygments by 'sudo easy_install Pygments' command and which is in '\usr\local\bin'  folder. Then still I get the error 'Package minted Error: You must have `pygmentize' installed to use this package.'

Comment: is `/usr/local/bin/` in your texstudio path? https://i.stack.imgur.com/MgOwG.png

Comment: No, How can find it, what should i put pygmentize there?

Comment: @sovon Can you start pygmentize from the command line?

Comment: yes, i can. I run 'pygmentize test.py' command and it works

Answer (score 1):

Go to the "Preferences" menu in Texmaker and choose the "Commands" tab. In line next to "PdfLaTeX" there should be

```
"/usr/texbin/pdflatex" -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode %.tex
```

change it to -

```
"/usr/texbin/pdflatex" -synctex=1 -shell-escape -interaction=nonstopmode %.tex
```

Got the solution from [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/48033/135597)