# Configure Texstudio with Macport (minted/pygments)

Tags: compiling, minted, mac, compilation-error, macports

I got a MacAir from work and I wanted to use LaTeX as usual. I installed Macport and used it to install texlive and texlive-extra, which should contain most packages. Then I installed python and pygments. Everything works so far. I can compile my files from the command line correctly without any errors.

But now I am facing a problem setting up the IDE. I wanted to install texstudio using macports, but it installed and configured a buch of stuff I did not wanted it to configure, therefore I aborted the process and installed it manually my downloading from the website and dragging it into the application (folder?).

I updated the compilation path inside texstudio to find pdflatex installed by macport (I don't quite understand, why I had to do that, because with the terminal I can access it from everywhere, but only doing so allowed me to compile from texstudio). But it still gives me an error for minted/pygments. Texstudio simply does not find it and I have no idea why this is happening, can you help me?

I trust my tex-files, therefore I usually use this (now adapted) command:

```
/opt/local/bin/pdflatex -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode --shell-escape %.tex
```

Comment: Actually this helped me a lot: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/48018/minted-not-working-on-mac